# PowerShell to slip a text file on specific string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to split a large text file  into several files based on a specific string. Every time I see the string ABCDE  - 3  I want to cut and paste the content up to that string in a new text file. I also  want to extract the last 4 of the social, last name and first name. The new text file needs be saved as first_name,last_name and last 4 of social.

See text file example and a bit of initial code. I would feel much more comfortbale doing it in Python but PowerShell is the only option.

```
$my_text = Get-Content .\ab.txt
$ssn_pattern = '([0-8]\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})'
ForEach ($file in my_text)
```

[image]

Comment: Your post describes two different problems and contains no question...

Comment: [1] use `Get-Content -Raw` to load the file as one multiline string. [2] use the `-split` operator to split on the string. [3] at that point the 3rd or 4th line of each block  will have the data you want ... use a simple set of splits OR use a regex pattern to grab the items.

Comment: What is the logic for the first and the last name? Can you share the text instead of an image?

Comment: There is a title(i.e. SIR) last name (i.e. SAREMO), first name (i.e. MIOTTI); each block needs to become a text file.I am not sure if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the firstname, lastname and the last 4 digits of the social, you could make use of capturing groups and use those groups when assembling the filename.

From your pattern, only the last 4 digits should be grouped.

You could use a pattern to start the match with TO: and from the next line get the values for the names and the number.

Then match all lines the do not start with ABCDE - 3 using a negative lookahead `(?!`

You can adjust the pattern and the code to match your exact text.

```
(?m)^[^\S\r\n]+TO:.*\r?\n\s*ATTN:\s*[A-Z]{3} ([^,\r\n]+),[^\S\r\n]*(.+?)[^\S\r\n]*[0-8]\d{2}-\d{2}-(\d{4})(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]+ABCDE - 3).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]+ABCDE - 3.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5hUDO5/1)

I constructed a code snippet using stackoverflow postings, so this might be improved. It basically comes down to load a raw string and get all the matches.

Then loop over all the matches and get the groups to assemble a filename an save the full match as the content.

If there are names which contain spaces and you don't want those to be in the filename, you could replace those with an empty string.

Example code:

```
$my_text = Get-Content -Raw ./Documents/stack-overflow/powershell/ab.txt

$pattern = "(?m)^[^\S\r\n]+TO:.*\r?\n\s*ATTN:\s*[A-Z]{3} ([^,\r\n]+),[^\S\r\n]*(.+?)[^\S\r\n]*[0-8]\d{2}-\d{2}-(\d{4})(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]+ABCDE - 3).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]+ABCDE - 3.*"
Select-String $pattern -input $my_text -AllMatches |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
        ForEach-Object {
            $fileName = -join ($_.groups[2].Value, $_.groups[1].Value, $_.groups[3].Value)
            Write-Host $fileName
            Set-Content -Path "your-path-here/$fileName.txt" -Value $_.Value
        }
```

When I run this, I get 2 files with the content for each match:

```
MIOTTISAREMO2222.txt
MIOTTSANREMO1111.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code. I now realize what you meant by the logic of text. In fact, the ABCDE is preceded by white space, and so is TO: and the SIR changes all of the time but still remains a 3 letter identifier. I am trying to change the match pattern. See reformatted test screenshot.

Comment: @PythonLearner Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/3dGWQI/1

Comment: @PythonLearner Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/5hUDO5/1

Comment: it works. thanks for the support and showing me the regex demo tool. it is very useful.